# how to change the UI based on the settings of a segmented control

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

In one `UIViewController`, I have a `UISegmentedControl`.

When I select segmented control.selectedindex==0, it will show a textfield.

When I select segmentedcontrol.selectedindex==1, it will show another segmented control instead of textfield.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific?? It doesn't let any one understand what you tend to do!!!

Comment: @Kevin, can you please recheck your question description! I am thinking there's some mistake. I can't understand.

Comment: Segmentedcontrol.selectedindex==0 gives textfield and segmentedcontrol.selectedindex==1 gives another segmentedcontrol.

Comment: Post any screenshot, if you can..

Comment: I've had a go at rephrasing the question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just have 2 segmented controls, but one of them hidden.
When selectedindex==1 on the first one, then unhide the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)yourSegmentControl:(id)sender{

switch ((((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex)) {
    case 0:
        {
           anothersegment.hide = YES;
           yourTextfield.hide = NO;
           break;
        }
case 1:
       {
           anothersegment.hide = NO;
           yourTextfield.hide = YES;
           break;
        }

    default:
        break;
}

}
```

Make sure that in your viewDidLoad you initialize your textfield and secondsegmentcontrol
both to hide = YES;